# iOS Swift - Position subview based on button frame (button is inside Vertical Stack View)

Tags: swift, uiview, frame, uistackview, addsubview

***Update***

*After adding convert method between rect and main View, the Y position is ok, but X coordinate is shifted to the right outside of the main view:
[Dropdown view(subview) is off main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlC71.png)
Below is button frame before and after convert method. Main view is 414 x 896. Dropdown menu somehow shifts to the right as on attached image.
button frame in stackView btnRect: (120.66666666666666, 0.0, 293.3333333333333, 30.0)
button frame in main view: cvtRect  (241.33333333333331, 190.0, 293.3333333333333, 30.0)
view:  Optional(>)*

**Goal.** I want to make a dropdown list by showing UIView with dropdown options below a button. Button is inside of Vertical Stack View. I add a TableView with dropdown options to this dropdown UIView.I want to click a button and have this UIView with TableView inside to show just below the button. Basically following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3DCPaEE4hQ  with the exception that my button is inside of Vertical Stack View.

**Issue.** UIView and TableView inside UIView show up ok when button is clicked. The issue is dropdown UIView's location that is always the same origin X=120, Y=0.

**This is how I try to do it:**

1. I have Vertical Stack with 4 rows
2. In 4th row I have label(width=120 almost same as X coordinate above) and a **button** that triggers UIView to show
3. I am using button to show dropdown list(basically UIView) that **should** appear just below button when the button is tapped, but it always appears at origin x=120 Y=0 , basically pinned to top of the right column in Vertical Stack View. Vertical Stack View has 1st column with labels, and second column with different controls like buttons etc.

```
func addTransparentView(frames: CGRect)
   {
      let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
      transparentView.frame = window?.frame ?? self.view.frame

      //some of the stuff I tried to at least centre dropdownUIView 
      //transparentView.center.x = window?.center.x ?? self.view.center.x
      //transparentView.center.y = window?.center.y ?? self.view.center.y

      self.view.addSubview(transparentView)

      tvPriority.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.width, width: frames.width, height: 0)

      //some of the stuff I tried to at least centre UIView
      //tvPriority.center = verticalStackView.convert(verticalStackView.center, from:tvPriority)     
      //tvPriority.center.x = view.center.x
      //tvPriority.center.y = view.center.y

      self.view.addSubview(tvPriority)
      tvPriority.layer.cornerRadius = 5

      transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
      let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTransparentView))
      transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
      transparentView.alpha = 0
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
         self.tvPriority.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 193)
      }, completion: nil)
   }
```

4. To successfully make dropdown list I need UIView to show up just below buttons frame(X, Y, width, height). But although button is in the 4th row which should be position with much higher Y value, buttons frame is always at X=120, Y=0, so my UIView is always pinned to this location way above button that is supposed to simulate dropdown.

**Questions**
**1.** What am I missing with positioning of the dropdown UIView? Why is buttons position Y=0 when the button is in 4th row of Vertical Stack View, with obviously much higher Y position? I also tried to simply centre this dropdown in the centre of screen but that also does not work.

**2.** I transitioned to iOS development from the world of web development, and I used dropdown a lot in my career. Should I just use Picker View instead? Or alert? What is the most common and most standard way of offering list of mutually exclusive options to user in Swift app?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your button is a subview of the stackView, so its frame is relative to the frame of the stackView.

To get its frame (rect) in the view's coordinate space, you'll want to use `.convert`. Assign this action to one of your buttons in the stackView:

**EDIT** Fixed the code example... I had not checked it before posting.

```
class ConvertViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var dropDownView: UIView!

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let btn = sender as? UIButton else {
            fatalError("Sender is not a button!")
        }
        guard let sv = btn.superview as? UIStackView else {
            fatalError("Sender is not in a stackView!")
        }

        let btnRect = btn.frame
        let cvtRect = sv.convert(btn.frame, to: view)
        print("button frame in stackView:", btnRect)
        print("button frame in main view:", cvtRect)

        let dropDownRect = dropDownView.bounds
        let cvtCenterX = cvtRect.origin.x + (cvtRect.size.width / 2.0)
        let viewX = cvtCenterX - (dropDownRect.width / 2.0)
        let newOrigin = CGPoint(x: viewX, y: cvtRect.minY + cvtRect.height)
        dropDownView.frame.origin = newOrigin

    }

}
```

If you look at the output in the debug console, you should see something like this:

```
button frame in stackView: (0.0, 114.0, 46.0, 30.0)
button frame in main view: (164.5, 489.5, 46.0, 30.0)
```

As you can see, the rect (frame) of my 4th button in my stackView has an origin of `0.0, 114.0`, but after converting it to my `view` coordinate space, the rect's origin is `164.5, 489.5`.

You can now position your "dropdown list" relative to the converted rect.

As a side note, you may want to look at `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps, I am very close now. I added let btnRect = btn.frame and
      let cvtRect = btn.convert(btn.frame, to: view). Now I am on the right Y position, just X coordinate is now off. btnRect: (120.66666666666666, 0.0, and after .convert cvtRect  (241.33333333333331, 190.0,  so this X=241 makes dropdown be positioned outside of view which is:   view:  Optional(<UIView: 0x7fe61fd86390; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; ). I am trying to figure out if view is somehow autoresizing, or how else can dropdown subview go outside of the main view, Thanks

Comment: Also thanks for the advice, PopoverPresentationController looks great, I will use it in future. I am still intrigued by the view, subviews and frame coordinates from above :-) and what makes them move

Comment: That `x = 241` will be the left-edge of the button. You can do whatever calculation you want for the `x` position... do, for example, if you want your "dropdown list" view to be centered underneath the button, you would probably get the center of the converted rect: `let cvtCenterX = cvtRect.origin.x + (cvtRect.size.width / 2.0)` and then position your view with `let viewX = cvtCenterX - (dropDownView.size.width / 2.0)`

Comment: @Bosniak - sorry... I had typed that code without testing it. I updated my answer -- should be accurate now.